# Forgotten Password form - Yii2 - Basic

Tags: email, yii2, forgot-password

I need a clue how to have a Forgotten email "form" that send code to some user(email box) and when he click the "code" for resetting the password,he is redirecting in the website and then he update his "forgotten password" , I make  forgot.php page in "site" folder , but can someone give me some clue what must be the logic in the `SiteController` and etc.

**forgot.php** (form for the forgotten password)

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
      <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: check the advanced template. I did a similar thing for a REST app which is a different case but I did grab everything from the advanced template. If I remember well it was about 2 actions, 2 models and 1 or 2 methods to add to the User class. the code was clear and easy to follow.

Comment: You can use this extension for user management, register and login.
[https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user)

Comment: @SalemOuerdani i got a lot of errors with grabbing everything from the advanced template :D

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

1. check user in db by email from the above email form, isExist?
2. exist -> generate reset_token+timestamp, and send email to user link+token+timestamp+email
3. User access the link, show form for new password + repeat password. But you need to set token validity by time (ex: 30 minutes).
4. if token valid, user can change password. else, redirect to page reset again